# socket io on method is not executing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I'm using react native with socket io, and im trying to figure out why socket io `.on` is not executing. Would anyone have an idea ?

for example client side socket io, console.log does not get called,

```
  socket.on('streamStarted', () => console.log('success'));
```

but io.connection gets called because i can see the  `console.log('user connected to main connection')` log. What could i be doing wrong ?

**server side**

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('user connected to main connection');
  socket.on('streamStarted', () => {
    console.log('user connected to stream');
    peerConnections.set(socket.id, socket);
  });
  socket.on('offerOrAnswer', data => {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('offerOrAnswer', data);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('disconnected');
    peerConnections.delete(socket.id);
  });
});
```

**react native client**

```
const socket = io('http://bf1f2213f095.ngrok.io');
React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('streamStarted', () => console.log('success'));
    socket.on('offerOrAnswer', sdp => {
      console.log('check for offer', sdp);
      // set sdp as remote description
      setOffer(sdp);
      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));
    });
    socket.on('candidate', candidate => {
      pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
    });

    startStream();
}, []);
```

Comment: seems like you did not emit streamStarted from server but listened on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your `socket.on('streamStarted', () => console.log('success'));` to be triggered - you have to emit this message somewhere:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit('streamStarted', {foo: 'bar'});
}, []);
```

Comment: what is the purpose of socket.on ? if i could just use emit ? thats my confusion

Comment: btw i added an emit to server, and did a client side emit before socket.on is called, so it works.

Comment: The point of socket io is a deeper question. May be this will help: https://www.ably.io/concepts/socketio